# useState variable isn't updated in chrome debugger but It's updated in ReactDevTools

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to run through array with the wheel event. I have a useState hook that initialices with value 0 when the component is mounted, and when I swipe on my trackpad, if I swipedown, the state count decrement 1 and viceversa. This value persona represents the current index position.

All good, the event and the state works as I expected. The problem is that when I trying to do some conditionals to control that the position of the array is not bigger or smaller than the size of that array in this piece of code:

```
if (Math.sign(e.deltaY) === -1) {
      console.log('swipe DOWN');
      if (persona > 0) {
        setPersona(prevPers => prevPers - 1);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('swipe UP');
      if (persona <= team.length) {
        setPersona(prevPers => prevPers + 1);
      }
    }
```

When I watch the persona value in Chrome Debugger, the value is equal to 0 ever, and due to this conditional:

```
if (persona > 0) {
 setPersona(prevPers => prevPers - 1);
}
```

the value ever increments, because the persona value is ever 0. However when I watch the persona value with ReactDevTools, the value is changing if I touch the wheel.

This is my code:

```
export const Equipo = () => {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const [persona, setPersona] = useState(0);

  const handleWheel = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setEvent(false);

    if (Math.sign(e.deltaY) === -1) {
      console.log('swipe DOWN');
      if (persona > 0) {
        setPersona(prevPers => prevPers - 1);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('swipe UP');
      if (persona <= team.length) {
        setPersona(prevPers => prevPers + 1);
      }
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('available to scroll');
      setEvent(true);
    }, 3000);
  };

  const setEvent = status => {
    status === true
      ? container.current.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false)
      : container.current.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setEvent(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className="bg-white h-screen w-full p-header pb-4 px-4 h-full flex justify-center align-middle items-center"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-p70 w-10/12 bg-red-500 overflow-hidden">
        {team[persona]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Equipo;
```

I dont know why the value in Chrome Debugger is diferent that the same value in ReactDevTools. This is the value when I debbugging:
[Persona value in Chrome Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpdNj.jpg)
As we can see, the persona console log is 2 but in the hover still prints 0.

And this is the value of persona in the ReactDevTools at the same point:
[The same value in ReactDevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQowG.jpg)

I don't know if I'm missing something very obvious but I don't understand why in that conditional the value of persona is still 0

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason why the persona value in your `setEvent` function is always 0 is because there is a closure around it that is created when the component first mounts and the `useEffect` hook runs.

Here's how I would solve your issue in the same way as you are currently doing:

I moved the handleWheel and setEvent functions into the useEffect function to indicate that their values aren't changing for the life of the effect. I also got rid of the references to the current values of persona by making it so that the setPersona calls don't go past their bounds.

```
export const Equipo = () => {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const [persona, setPersona] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWheel = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setEvent(false);

      if (Math.sign(e.deltaY) === -1) {
        console.log('swipe DOWN');
        setPersona((prevPers) => {
          Math.max(0, prevPers - 1);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('swipe UP');
        setPersona((prevPers) => Math.min(team.length, prevPers + 1));
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('available to scroll');
        setEvent(true);
      }, 3000);
    };

    const setEvent = (status) => {
      status === true
        ? container.current.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false)
        : container.current.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false);
    };
    setEvent(true);
    return () => {
      setEvent(false);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className="bg-white h-screen w-full p-header pb-4 px-4 h-full flex justify-center align-middle items-center"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-p70 w-10/12 bg-red-500 overflow-hidden">
        {team[persona]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Equipo;
```

---

Here's another way I would do it by using a throttle function instead of timeouts. This way I believe is cleaner, as you don't need to worry about refs as much and timeouts. It is also the more normal way of making sure a function only runs every t period of time.

Instead of binding the event listener yourself, it's easier to just let react take care of it.

Throttling code itself is from https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-throttling-and-debouncing-973131c1ba07. Though you could just as easily use lodash's throttle function.

```
export const Equipo = () => {
  const [persona, setPersona] = useState(0);
  const handleWheel = useCallback(
    throttle((e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      if (Math.sign(e.deltaY) === -1) {
        console.log('swipe DOWN');
        setPersona((prevPers) => {
          Math.max(0, prevPers - 1);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('swipe UP');
        setPersona((prevPers) => Math.min(team.length, prevPers + 1));
      }
    }, 3000),
    [team.length]
  );


  return (
    <div
      onWheel={handleWheel}
      className="bg-white h-screen w-full p-header pb-4 px-4 h-full flex justify-center align-middle items-center"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-p70 w-10/12 bg-red-500 overflow-hidden">
        {team[persona]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Equipo;

function throttle(f, t) {
  let lastCall;
  return function (args) {
    let previousCall = lastCall;
    lastCall = Date.now();
    if (
      previousCall === undefined || // function is being called for the first time
      lastCall - previousCall > t
    ) {
      // throttle time has elapsed
      f(args);
    }
  };
}
```

---

Explanation of why persona was always 0:

In Javascript, when a function is created, it creates what is known as a closure, where it pulls in all the variables that exist in it's scope and allows the function to always be able to access those.[MDN on closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

What was happening is that when the `useEffect` ran on mount, it would pull in the current version of the `setEvent` function and that would have access to the current version of the `handleWheel` function. `setEvent` would bind that original version of `handleWheel` to the div and would never have a chance to update the version of `handleWheel` that was bound. Due to closures, the original `handleWheel` function has a closure around persona when persona was 0. And since there's always a new instance of the persona variable on each re-render, the closured variable was never updated.

Essentially this is what your code looked like in the useEffect. Hopefully this will help you see why you were running into issues.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const setEvent = (status) => {
    const handleWheel = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setEvent(false);

      if (Math.sign(e.deltaY) === -1) {
        console.log('swipe DOWN');
        if (persona > 0) {
          setPersona((prevPers) => prevPers - 1);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('swipe UP');
        if (persona <= team.length) {
          setPersona((prevPers) => prevPers + 1);
        }
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('available to scroll');
        setEvent(true);
      }, 3000);
    };
    status === true
      ? container.current.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false)
      : container.current.removeEventListener('wheel', handleWheel, false);
  };
  setEvent(true);
}, []);
```

Comment: I perfectly understand that is more cleaner let that react take care of the events doing onWheel={function}, and I think that is so much better idea use throttle function to control  when the function runs. But I dont understand why the persona value is 0 yet. The use effect is only for create the event. Why handwheel and setEvent should be in the useEffect? for me, useEffect runs only once, whe the component is mounted and It just creates a event, the function handleWheel runs when I touch the wheel, why this function should be in the useEffect? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: I added further details about what the issue was. If it doesn't make sense to you, it might be best to start a chat on here so I can explain it better.

Comment: Oh god!!! Thank you so much, this is the answer that I need :)

Comment: For another doubts about useEffect "lifeCycles" or behaviour, I found this blog by Dan Abramov, maybe it will can help other doubts about it. https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/